# Conventions: $e^{ikx}$ vs. $e^{-ikx}$

Tags: conventions, fourier-transform

What are pros and cons to use a negative or positive sign.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: I personally get anxious when I see an exponential without a negative sign

Comment: I do not think there is such a preference, however it is at least opinion based and so off-topic.

Comment: @user2723984  How about quaternions and octonians?

Comment: @Charlie Photonics/Optics/Laser physics.

Answer (score 4):

I think that physicists (certainly I  myself) prefer to write $e^{-i\omega t}$ and $e^{ikx}$ when expanding things out:
$$
f(t)=\int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \tilde f(\omega) e^{-i\omega t}
$$
but
$$
f(x)=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi} \tilde f(k) e^{ik  x}.
$$
This is to agree with the usage in quantum mechanics where $\hbar k$ is momentum and $\hbar \omega$ is energy.

Of course it's the other way round when computing the Fourier transforms:
$$
\tilde f(\omega)= \int dt f(t) e^{i\omega t}
$$
$$
\tilde f(k)= \int dt f(x) e^{-i kx}
$$

Comment: Yes I knew about this.. This is why I prefer it as well. I probably should have asked on the EE SE why they use this silly convention!